# Minimal search endpoints?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms

Assume that for each building in a city there is a known subset of the city's buildings that can be seen from that building (being in a building counts as "seeing a building" as well so for every building you can see at least one building, the building you are in).

Develop an efficient algorithm for visiting the minimum number of buildings given a list of buildings you want to see.

More specifically assume you have a list of all buildings in a city with a list of all buildings you can see from each building:

```
{ 1: [1, 2], 2: [2], 3: [3, 1] }
```

And you then want to implement a function like:

```
seeBuildings([1,2]) -> [1] (list of buildings to visit)
```

How can this be efficiently implemented when the number of buildings is large (~10,000) and the number of buildings visible from a given building can vary from between 1 (only see self) and 30?

Is there some data structure that can be precomputed then saved so searches are cheap thereafter?

Comment: This problem is called Dominating Set, and it's NP-hard, so it's very unlikely that any algorithm exists that will efficiently solve every instance to optimality.

Comment: @j_random_hacker can you point me at some approximations that are reasonable for the size of data I'm looking at?  This will run on a phone and could take 5-10 sec and that would be fine but probably not ok for it burn 100% CPU for much longer than that.

Comment: None have good bounds, so I would probably use a simple greedy search, possibly followed by local improvement heuristics as time permits.